SiC461 regulators unpredictably dying under load
I am having problems with a design using SiC461 regulators.
I attached a snippet of the relevant schematic file. The problem I am facing is that under load (powering an LED strip with peak current of around 6 A) the regulators seem to be dying randomly, most of them with no voltage on output (open-circuit), some as a short-circuit. This issue seems to be partially load dependent as I control the connected LED strips via PWM and a low-side MOSFET switch and the issue seems to be not present on less than 10% PWM duty cycle.
Some of the regulators have a scorch mark above the letter S (see attached file). The circuit resumes normal function after the dead regulator IC is replaced.
I also attached screenshots of relevant part of the finished PCB layout. The circuit is powered by a 48 V 350 W switching power supply. I checked the output voltage from the regulator with and oscilloscope and everything seems to be in order (no excessive voltage ripple, etc.). The PCB with regulators is attached to a chunky aluminium enclosure via a thermal pad, measured temperature of the package under full load (with an IR thermometer) is around 60-70 °C.




EDIT (25.4.2024)
I tried various input capacitors reworked directly onto the IC input pads. After trying multiple values I settled on 2.2 uF (would like to go higher but I cannot get my hands on a high enough rated MLCC cap of that capacity locally and have none in storage). Screen caps from an oscilloscope (before/after):


This seems to be the issue, will follow up with another edit after more rigorous on-site testing.

Input decoupling capacitors missing?

From the datasheet on Cin: A 4.7 μF ceramic input capacitance is a suitable starting point. I see a single 680uF elect. and a single 0.1uF ceramic cap for both chips in your design.  I would look at the noise on the input as close to the chip pin as you can.  Or rework a ceramic cap in right next to each of the chips.

I will add a 4.7uF cap right next to the ICs and see how the noise looks.

How hot are the chips getting? What kind of heatsink do you have on them? The datasheet suggests that the maximum efficiency is about 96% for your configuration. With almost 150 W of output power, that's 5+ watts of loss in the regulator overall, and a significant fraction of that will be in the integrated switching transistors. That's an awfully small package for that kind of power.

As i mentioned in the post, the ICs are adequately cooled and used in a temperature-controlled environment. This should not be a problem.
